# Spring Rest Template mocking with Spock

Tags: java, spring, mocking, spock, resttemplate

Can anyone show me an example, how to test RestTemplate using Spock.
My classes looks like this:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private EndpointUrlProvider endpointUrlProvider;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public SomeResponse doSomePostRequest(HttpEntity<?> httpEntity) throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> response;
            try{
                response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endpointUrlProvider.getSomeUrl(),httpEntity,SomeResponse.class);
            } catch (Exception e){
                throw new Exception("Exception occured during post for:" + httpEntity.getBody().getClass().getSimpleName() + " Cause: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
                return response.getBody();
            }
            throw new Exception("Error during " + response.getBody().getClass().getSimpleName() + "Http status is diffrent than 200: " + response.getBody().toString());
        }
    }
```

Tests:

```
class SomeTest extends Specification {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock {
        postForEntity(_, _, SomeResponse.class) >> new ResponseEntity(new SomeResponse(), HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    @Autowired
    SomeService someService

    def "someTest"() {
        when:
        SomeResponse someResponse = someService.doSomePostRequest(new HttpEntity<>(new SomeBody(), new HttpHeaders()))
        then:
        someResponse == new SomeResponse()
    }
}
```

The major problem is mocking behaviour of RestTemplate,I looking for solution how to do it in proper way. I'm dont use spring boot.

Comment: What does not work? As for `someResponse == new SomeResponse()` this will only work if `SomeResponse` has overriden `equals` otherwise this will definitely fail.

Comment: Thank you for advice but I the problem is somewhere else when I run my test postForEntity() method is hitting to the endpoint instead of returning value declared in mock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation is following:

You create new `RestTemplate` in your service class.

```
  private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Then you create mock in tests and call your service method:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock {
            postForEntity(_, _, SomeResponse.class) >> new ResponseEntity(new SomeResponse(), HttpStatus.OK)
        }
                  ....
    someService.doSomePostRequest
```

But your service still has usual rest template inside. You should inject mock object. I would suggest you doing it through constructor. So change your code to:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

private EndpointUrlProvider endpointUrlProvider;
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
public SomeService(EndpointUrlProvider endpointUrlProvider, RestTemplate restTemplate){
  this.endpointUrlProvider = endpointUrlProvider;
  this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```

And your test will be:

```
class SomeTest extends Specification {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock {
        postForEntity(_, _, SomeResponse.class) >> new ResponseEntity(new SomeResponse(), HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    SomeService someService = new SomeService (  null, restTemplate);

    def "someTest"() {
        when:
        SomeResponse someResponse = someService.doSomePostRequest(new HttpEntity<>(new SomeBody(), new HttpHeaders()))
        then:
        someResponse == new SomeResponse()
    }
}
```

Now your service object will call method on injected MOCK, not usual `RestTemplate`

p.s.

Constructor injection considered to be a good practice by spring.

It's better to create a RestTemplate bean and inject it everywhere, than create new object in all services.

Comment: I can't inject RestTemplate in constructor with @Autowired annotation because it is non-bean class. Also EndpointUrlProvider should be injected. ;)

Comment: @KamilDS Make it a bean. Just add RestTemplate bean definition to your spring context.

Comment: I see that works. But how can I inject my endpointUrlProvider and mock class of RestTempate in one constructor?. I tried autowired endpointUrlProvider in my test class and pass it through constructor but it is null when i fire my test.

Comment: @KamilDS you could create spring test context, create urlProvider bean there and autowire it to your test. Then pass it to constructor. Or make url provider to be mock as well

Comment: @KamilDS it looks like another question :D You could ask it in Spring section e.g. "How to use spring beans in tests"

Comment: this bracket is missing, above hint helped me to resolve my issue, but spent 1.5hours.  RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock`()` {
        postForEntity(_, _, SomeResponse.class) >> new ResponseEntity(new SomeResponse(), HttpStatus.OK)
    }