# How do I test the function in service that make restTemplate post method in Spock?

Tags: java, spring, testing, groovy, spock

I have a simple service that I want to test with Spock framework and groovy.

I was reading this post and followed and modified as this post says.
But I still have the issue with my testing function.
[Spring Rest Template mocking with Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288305/spring-rest-template-mocking-with-spock/47309415)

This post suggested to make a constructor with beans. luckily I have bean but constructor, I had to make it. (To be honest, I did not want to as my code works fine without the constructor given the @Bean annotation attached to RestTemplate in config)

The problem is I am guessing that my restTemplate is not correctly mocked. That is why when I try to call my testing function, it is still calling the actual restTempalte postEntity and it would gives me back null.

And it explodes when I do `response.body()` as response is a null....

But if it does not mock, then how the other post was able to solve it?

I appreciate if you could spot the bug in my code.

Following is my code

```
// config.groovy
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
  return new RestTemplate()
}
```

```
// MyService
@Service
class MyService {
  @Resource
  RestTemplate restTemplate

  MyService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate
  }

  def callEndPoint(String arg) {
    response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
      "http://url",
      new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders(["content-type": "application/type"])),
      String.class
    );

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    Map result = objectMapper.readValue(response.body, Map.class) <-- exception thrown
    return result ["data"]["root"]["username"];
  }
}
```

```
// test
class Test extends Specification {
  private String URL = "http://url"
  MyService myService

  HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity()
  RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock {
    postForEntity(URL, httpEntity, String.class) >> new ResponseEntity("something", HTTPStatus.ok)

  void setup() {
    this.myService = new MyService(restTemplate)
  }

  def "restTemplate"() {
    given:
    def arg = "something args"
    def result = this.myService.callEndpoint(args) <- null pointer exception thrown
  
    when:
    def resutls = "this is the result"
    then:
    result.getBody() == results
  }
}
```

Comment: I comprehensively answered your question several days ago. Please be polite enough to react, either by accepting and upvoting it or by commenting, if there is anything you do not understand or disagree with.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, both the service class and the test contain syntax errors and do not compile. Did you even test what you posted here, or did you just copy & paste, then edit the original code in order to mess it up so much? There are lots of typos in variable names, missing curly braces, misspelled class names and constants.

Please also use Java comments like `// <- exception here` when writing comments right into your source code, otherwise it does not compile when others want to compile it in order to help you. Do not just omit the `//`.

Now with regard to

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock {
    postForEntity(URL, httpEntity, String.class) >> new ResponseEntity("something", HTTPStatus.ok)
```

the missing closing curly brace is not the only problem, but also:

- Better rename the field `URL` to `url`, because otherwise the name could collide with an imported class `URL`. Field and variable names should start with lower-case characters.
- The HTTP entity you create as a parameter does not match the one used in the method under test. Better just match any parameter using `_` here, that is easier.
- `HTTPStatus.ok` should be `HttpStatus.OK`. The fact that Groovy is more dynamic than Java and does not strictly check names but determine them during runtime seems to trip you up. Maybe you are not very experienced in programming, so please be careful. Software development is all about the details, you cannot just write anything.
- The `.class` in `String.class` is optional in Groovy, you can omit it. But that is just cosmetics, no actual problem.
- In the `ResponseEntity` constructor, the body must be JSON, because that is what your method under test expects and parses. Otherwise, you will get Jackson errors later. The JSON must match the expected structure, too.

So how about this?

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71289094

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

import javax.annotation.Resource

@Service
class MyService {
  @Resource
  RestTemplate restTemplate

  MyService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate
  }

  def callEndPoint(String arg) {
    def response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
      "http://url",
      new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders(["content-type": "application/type"])),
      String.class
    )

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    Map result = objectMapper.readValue(response.body, Map.class)
    return result ["data"]["root"]["username"];
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71289094

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyServiceTest extends Specification {
  String url = "http://url"
  JsonBuilder json = new JsonBuilder()
    .data {
      root {
        username "admin"
      }
    }
  RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock() {
    postForEntity(url, _, String) >>
      new ResponseEntity(json.toPrettyString(), HttpStatus.OK)
  }
  MyService myService = new MyService(restTemplate)

  def "restTemplate"() {
    expect:
    this.myService.callEndPoint("dummy") == "admin"
  }
}
```

Now the test passes.

[Try it in the Groovy web console.](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&gist=66e0ddea1b399234788b3ea488fba1b0)

Comment: **Update:** I added a link to the Groovy web console, so you can directly execute the code there. I just added a few `@Grab` annotations in order to fetch all the necessary dependencies.