# Mocking Extended RestTemplate using parent's methods

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spock, spring-resttemplate

I have this class that extends from `RestTemplate`

```
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
@Component
public class MyOwnRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {

    public MyOwnRestTemplate(String referenceService, int readTimeoutRestTemplate, int connectionTimeoutRestTemplate) {
        super();
        setErrorHandler(new SomeErrorHandler());
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeoutRestTemplate);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeoutRestTemplate);
        List<SomeClassInterceptor> interceptors = Collections.singletonList(new SomeClassHttpRequestInterceptor(referenceService));

        setRequestFactory(new InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, interceptors));

    }
}
```

Now, I need to Mock with `Spock` based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47309415 something like this code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock {
    postForEntity(_, _, SomeResponse.class) >> new ResponseEntity(new SomeResponse(), HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Now my code:

```
private MyOwnRestTemplate myOwnRestTemplate

void setup() {
    myOwnRestTemplate = Mock {
        //Here I don't know using parent's methods!!
    }
```

**How to get access to methods of parent as `getForEntity`, `getForObject`, `postForLocation`?**

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings thanks, I haven't still problem because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried to just use `postForEntity(_, _, SomeResponse.class) >> new ResponseEntity(new SomeResponse(), HttpStatus.OK)` , or whatever you want to mock?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings yes, but it doesn't recognized....

Comment: Just the syntax highlighting, or didn't it work at all? Could you share what you tried?